# jQuery hook onto appended element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having a bit of trouble figuring out how I can hook onto a recently added element.

The idea being, add an element twice, and then set different css properties based on the elements that have been added.

```
while(i < str.length){
    chars = str[i];
    dupText = "<span>" + chars + "</span>";

    var fh = $hc.append(dupText);  //need to hook onto these 2 elements
    var sh = $hc.append(dupText);

    var width = fh.width()/2;

    //These two lines don't apply any changes to the appended elements.
    $(sh[0]).width(width);
    $(fh[0]).css('text-indent', -width);

    i++;
}
```

However, this doesn't appear to do anything. What would be the best way to hook onto both of those elements individually to make CSS changes?

Javascript solutions are also welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by "hook onto"?  What specifically isn't working?

Comment: @David the lines making changes to the elements are not working. so while `fh` and `sh` get the proper width, no changes are made to the elements.

Comment: try `$(sh[0]).style.width(width);
    $(fh[0]).css('text-indent', -width.toString());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache element to be appended as `jQuery-element`

```js
var $hc = $('#parent');
var str = 'Rayon';
var i = 0;
while (i < str.length) {
  var chars = str[i];
  var dupText = "<span>" + chars + "</span>";
  var elem = $(dupText);
  $hc.append(elem);
  var width = elem.width() / 2;
  elem.width(width);
  elem.css('text-indent', -width);
  i++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='parent'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `append` method doesn't return the appended item, it returns the element that you appended to, which means your `sh` and `fh` variables both refer to your `$hc` element. Instead, get the last child of `$hc` for each assignment:

```
fh = $hc.append(dupText).children().last();
sh = $hc.append(dupText).children().last();

width = fh.width()/2;

sh.width(width);
fh.css('text-indent', -width);
```

**Pro tip**: use debugging to test your assumptions. In this case, you assumed that the `fh` and `sh` variables contained references to the appended element. Outputting those variables to the console, or using a breakpoint to observe their contents, would have shown otherwise.

Comment: Thanks! that worked well, but went with the other answer as I thought caching the element would be a more reliable way to ensure the element I am changing is the same one that was added.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) like this.

```
while(i < str.length){
chars = str[i];
dupText1 = "<span>" + chars + "</span>";
// add css for dupText1 element
dupText2 = $(dupText1).clone();
// add css for dupText2 element.

var fh = $hc.append(dupText1);  
var sh = $hc.append(dupText2);

i++;}
```